# How can I display a block of HTML in my Firefox add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I've used XUL to create a toolbarbutton. When I click on this button, I want a div to popup in the same style as clicking on an extension in Google Chrome. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add HTML elements to XUL document, you have to define the namespace for it:

```
<window
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
```

Then you can add HTML elements, but you have to prefix the tag names with the namespace. Like this:

```
<vbox>
  <description>This is XUL element</description>
  <html:div>This is HTML element</html:div>
</vbox>
```

You can find more info and examples in the [official documentetion at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_Tutorial/Adding_HTML_Elements).

Comment: Your question is "How to display HTML in XUL", so this is the answer. But if you just want to display a popup, it will be much easier for you to use native XUL elements for that. Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/PopupGuide

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin" type="text/css"?>
  <window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <button label="Details" type="panel">
      <panel id="search-panel">
        <label control="name" value="Name:"/>
        <textbox id="name"/>
      </panel>
  </button>

   </window>
```

Button can be replaced with toolbarbutton